# why spend a lot of time in sparkstreaming to elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch, apache-kafka, spark-streaming, flume

I'm trying save some logdata to elasticsearch, flume -> kafka ->sparkstreaming -> elasticsearch. In the step : sparkstreaming to elasticsearch, we spend a lot of time.
Roughly, saving 1000 data to elasticsearch need one minute.

```
  message.foreachRdd(rdd=>{

//step 1. According to index and type of ES to categorize the rdd and save to a hashmap

 val logRdds = new collection.mutable.HashMap[String, RDD[String]]
 logRdds += (“index1/type1” -> rdd.filter(x => isIndexAndType(x, “index1”,”type1”)))
 logRdds += (“index2/type2” -> rdd.filter(x => isIndexAndType(x, “index2”,”type2”)))
 logRdds += (“index3/type3” -> rdd.filter(x => isIndexAndType(x, “index3”,”type3”)))
 logRdds += (“index4/type4” -> rdd.filter(x => isIndexAndType(x, “index4”,”type4”)))
 logRdds += (“index5/type5” -> rdd.filter(x => isIndexAndType(x, “index5”,”type5”)))
 logRdds += (“index6/type6” -> rdd.filter(x => isIndexAndType(x, “index6”,”type6”)))
 logRdds += (“index7/type7” -> rdd.filter(x => isIndexAndType(x, “index7”,”type7”)))
 logRdds += (“index8/type8” -> rdd.filter(x => isIndexAndType(x, “index8”,”type8”)))
 logRdds += (“index9/type9” -> rdd.filter(x => isIndexAndType(x, “index9”,”type9”)))
 logRdds += (“index10/type10” -> rdd.filter(x => isIndexAndType(x, “index10”,”type10”)))
 logRdds += (“index11/type11” -> rdd.filter(x => isIndexAndType(x, “index11”,”type11”)))

//step 2. deal with the rdd(map and filter)

 for((k,v) <- logRdds){
   logRdds(k) = v.map(x => getLogContent(x))
}

 for((k,v) <- logRdds){

    logRdds(k) = v.filter(x => isJson(x))
}

//step 3. Save json to elasticsearch

logRdds.foreach(item =>{

  if(item._2.count() > 0 ){
    EsSpark.saveJsonToEs(item._2, item._1)
     }

   })
 })
```

Why spend a lot of time in sparkstreaming to elasticsearch?
A lot of rdd? How can I improve the code?

Comment: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-bulk.html

Comment: Sending log data to Elasticsearch - sounds like you should be using logstash rather than stringing 3 different technologies together (https://www.elastic.co/products/logstash)